# Разбить список постов на две колонки

Tags: css

Есть список постов. У части постов класс `left`, у другой `right`.

Мне нужно как-то сформировать 2 псевдо-колонки, где посты с классом `left` слева, а с `right` справа.
Причем реализовать это надо с помощью CSS, так как по определенным причинам я не могу реализовать это по нормальному (создать две колонки и выводить посты в соответствующих).

Я начал с применения свойства float, но обнаружил, что между постами в таком случае есть вертикальные 'пробелы'.

Я понимаю, что это звучит ужасно глупо. Такое вообще возможно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб не было пробелов margin:0;

А вообще я всегда заворачиваю в дивы).

css:

```
.left,.right,#post_wall{
    width:300px;
}

.left{
    text-align:left;
}

.right{
    text-align:right;
}

#post_wall{
    height:100px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="post_wall">
    <div class="left">я слева</div>
    <div class="right">я справа</div>
    <div class="left">я слева</div>
    <div class="right">я справа</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 30em;
}

.left {
  order: -1;
}

.right {
  order: 1;
}

section:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="left">Left again</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="right">Right again</div>
  <div class="left">Left once more</div>
  <div class="right">Right once more</div>
</section>
```